# How to find levels of managers in self-referenced key

Tags: sql

So I have a table employees(ID, MaganerID)
My task is to find 2-nd level manager who is not getting any bonuses(another table)
I'm stuck here. Any advice what should I do next?

```
SELECT ID  
FROM Employees   
WHERE ID NOT IN (Select EmployeeID FROM Bonuses)      
 AND ID IN (Select LeaderID FROM Employees WHERE LeaderID IS NOT NULL)     
 AND ID NOT IN (Select ID FROM Employees WHERE ID <> LeaderID)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Well since you want a level 2 manager is much more simple:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E2.ID
FROM Employees E
INNER JOIN Employees E1 ON E1.ID = E.ManagerID
INNER JOIN Employees E2 ON E2.ID = E1.ManagerID
INNER JOIN Bonuses B ON B.EmployeeID = E2.ID AND B.Bonus = 0
```

You could also use the Recurse option using the `WITH` keyword if you are using TSQL. If you simply dont want to not exists on the other table just reverse the last bool check on the join.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably by second-level manager you mean where their EmployeeID is somebody else's LeaderID, whose EmployeeID in turn is a third person's LeaderID?
I think currently you'll just get first level managers.

This should work... I've included your final WHERE statement, although you don't explain what that's for. Do you really want to exlude records where the ID is different to the LeaderID?

```
SELECT L2.ID  
FROM Employees E   
JOIN Employees L1 on E.LeaderID = L1.ID
JOIN Employees L2 on L1.LeaderID = L2.ID
WHERE L2.ID not in (SELECT EmployeeID from Bonuses)
AND L2.ID NOT IN (Select ID FROM Employees WHERE ID <> LeaderID)
```